# JMS Active MQ Load balance URL

Tags: web8.5, cache-channel-service, jms

We have configured Active MQ for Tridion CCS using the load balance domain name
We are getting below error.

> Could not connect to broker URL:
>   tcp://deployerlive.com:61616?soTimeout=5000 Caused by:
>   javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not
>   send his wire format. Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wire format
>   negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format. ERROR
>   CacheChannel - Could not connect to Cache Channel Service on startup,
>   will attempt again in 60000ms com.tridion.cache.CacheException: JMS
>   Exception occurred. Attempting setting up JMS connectivity later

Can you please help me in resolving above error.

Comment: This article may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191513/wire-format-negotiation-timeout-peer-did-not-send-his-wire-format?

Comment: Have you considered configuring ActiveMQ with a failover url? For example: failover:(tcp://SERVERADDRESS1:61616,tcp://SERVERADDRESS2:61616)?randomize=false&amp;priorityBackup=true&amp;timeout=5000. See https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html for more information.

Comment: When we tried with above option above error resolved, Can't we use LB URL for ActiveMQ?  If i want to configure LB url what configurations required?